# Iterate JSON & append to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I've searched but can't seem to get a working example specifically for what i'm trying to do here. 
I'm working with an api that returns a bunch of lines of json. I would like to iterate through all of the key/value pairs and store only the relevant ones to another dictionary to be used/referenced later on.

What I have tried works for the most part, however when I print the contents of the dictionary object it only returns the newest key/value pair... I would like to know how to APPEND to the dictionary, so that when I print it, I get a nice long list of key/value pairs.

Here's the code:

```
r=requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p)
inbound_dict={}
inbound=json.loads(r.text)
for item in inbound['messages']:
    inbound_dict[item['conversationId']] = item['body']
print(inbound_dict)
```

I know it's got to be something simple I'm missing. I've tried `inbound_dict.append()` but obviously that's not quite right.

You can see in the image below where the red lines are, that just shows where each of the different json "instances" end. For context, this is an sms messaging app and each json response represents a single message.

[image: Here is a sample output of the returned json that I need to parse through]

And, here are the first 2 "json's" in text form:

```
b'{"id":1005672,"messages":[{"id":4461048,"body":"Mnow test test","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":0,"status":"RECEIVED","error":null,"kind":"INCOMING","outgoing":false,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1576783232355,"attachments":[]},{"id":4461049,"body":"THIS NUMBER DOES NOT CURRENTLY ACCEPT TEXT MESSAGES PLEASE CALL (716) 444-4444 TO WORK WITH ONE OF OUR INTAKE SPECIALISTS","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":0,"status":"RECEIVED","error":null,"kind":"AUTO_RESPONSE","outgoing":true,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1576783233546,"attachments":[]},{"id":4620511,"body":"test sms,test sms","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":17297,"status":"DELIVERED","error":null,"kind":"API","outgoing":true,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1577987093930,"attachments":[]},...
```

Comment: This depends on your data. You should print(item['conversationId']) to show what keys you are creating.

Comment: Instead of the pic, can you paste the actual text here? its easier to read and manipulate

Comment: I updated the post with the text version. And I'm not sure if that's correct what you say about not being valid json... it does work to manipulate it with the json package, so.. not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
r=requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p)
inbound_dict = {}
inbound=json.loads(r.text)
for item in inbound['messages']:
    inbound_dict[item['id']] = item['body']
print(inbound_dict)
```

Given this data:

```
'{"id": 1005672, "messages": [{"id": 4461048, "body": "Mnow test test", "conversationId": 1005672, "locationId": 2045, "contactId": 12792806, "assignedUserId": 0, "status": "RECEIVED", "error": "", "kind": "INCOMING", "outgoing": false, "reviewRequest": false, "type": "SMS", "readDate": 0, "respondedDate": 0, "sentDate": 1576783232355, "attachments": []}, {"id": 4461049, "body": "THIS NUMBER DOES NOT CURRENTLY ACCEPT TEXT MESSAGES PLEASE CALL (716) 444-4444 TO WORK WITH ONE OF OUR INTAKE SPECIALISTS", "conversationId": 1005672, "locationId": 2045, "contactId": 12792806, "assignedUserId": 0, "status": "RECEIVED", "error": "", "kind": "AUTO_RESPONSE", "outgoing": true, "reviewRequest": false, "type": "SMS", "readDate": 0, "respondedDate": 0, "sentDate": 1576783233546, "attachments": []}, {"id": 4620511, "body": "test sms,test sms", "conversationId": 1005672, "locationId": 2045, "contactId": 12792806, "assignedUserId": 17297, "status": "DELIVERED", "error": "", "kind": "API", "outgoing": true, "reviewRequest": false, "type": "SMS", "readDate": 0, "respondedDate": 0, "sentDate": 1577987093930, "attachments": []}]}'
```

The output is:

```
{    
    4461048: 'Mnow test test', 
    4461049: 'THIS NUMBER DOES NOT CURRENTLY ACCEPT TEXT MESSAGES PLEASE CALL (716) 444-4444 TO WORK WITH ONE OF OUR INTAKE SPECIALISTS', 
    4620511: 'test sms,test sms'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information- I think you're close but still not quite there. With what I posted in the original post, this is returned: {198273: 'this is my message'}, which is nice, exactly what I want... however I want a bunch of those... like a dictionary full of little dictionaries, that I can reference later on in the program.

Comment: Without knowing the full data type of the json response and what you want your output to look like - I don't think I understand what you want

Comment: I will add a sample of the json to the original post... I would like the output to look like this: {28736: 'hi... test message', 837485: 'hi, test message 2', 8436778: 'hi again!'} ... just like a list of the key and value pairs contained in a dictionary. Or, if there's a better way to store the info so I can use it later?

Comment: Again that's only 1 part of the equation. I know the output you want but I don't know the input.

Comment: I updated the question with the response from the server

Comment: Do you want the data structure to be the following: `{"conversationId": [{"messageId": "message"}, ...]}`
as in a dictionary of a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @t4keheart updated. I think you were using the wrong key :D

Comment: Yes this was actually what I was after! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
# initialize variables:
inbound_dictionary_list = []

for item in inbound['messages']:

    # extract key, value:
    key = item['conversationId']
    value = item['body']

    # pack into dictionary object:
    parsed_item = {key:value}

    # update existing dictionary:
    inbound_dictionary_list.append(parsed_item)
```

Details: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp

Comment: I don't think you understand... I don't know what I want to update with because i'm trying to iterate through the json to be added with a for loop... there are hundreds of lines to be added.

Comment: My apologies - I've updated my answer to fit your context. Let me know if I still misunderstood.

Comment: This is closer I think, however when I print the results of the inbound_dict object, I'm still only getting 1 key:value pair... the newest one... where in reality there are maybe 30 contained in the initial request response.

Comment: It sounds like all the keys are the same - meaning the key, value pair is overwritten with each iteration of the for loop. Instead you can try creating a list of dictionaries - I've edited my code to reflect this.

Comment: Should be there now - let me know if it doesn't work.